# Recursive upgradeable lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode exception while accessing Sitecore configuration while initiating the IoC container

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection

When trying to access the Sitecore Configuration Factory to read a setting while configuring services in the IoC container the below exception is thrown.

```
public class ServicesConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
{
    public ServicesConfigurator()
    {
        Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetConfiguration();
    }
}
```

I know, that this is because the configuration factory itself is configured in the container, and is not yet available, so the question is, how do I access values from the Sitecore configuration, before the configuration factory is available through the container? Accessing the factory through the Service Locator throws the same exception, eventhough the factory is already registered at this point.

#### Source Error:

> ### Recursive upgradeable lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.
>
> `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetConfiguration();`

#### Stack Trace:

> [LockRecursionException: Recursive upgradeable lock acquisitions not
>   allowed in this mode.]
>   System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLockCore(TimeoutTracker
>   timeout) +3839391
>   System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock(TimeoutTracker
>   timeout) +45
>   Sitecore.Threading.Locks.UpgradeableReadScope..ctor(ReaderWriterLockSlim
>   mutex) +107
>   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.get_ServiceProvider() +85 
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.<.cctor>b__0() +9
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +709    System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +191
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetConfiguration() +44
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +138
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +105
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12
>   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ConfiguratorsConfigurator.b__0(XmlNode
>   x) +164    System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +223
>   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection
>   serviceCollection) +179
>   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection
>   serviceCollection) +160
>   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServiceProviderBuilder.ConfigureServiceCollection()
>   +142    Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ConfigureServiceProvider()
>   +256    Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.get_ServiceProvider() +153
>   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.SitecorePerRequestScopeModule..ctor() +13
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +138
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +105
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1499
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +191    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture) +27
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[]
>   args) +82
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1
>   moduleList) +229
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
>   +1114    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +140
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +539
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +125    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +731

Comment: Why are you doing this in the constructor? There's a `Configure` method you're supposed to use: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/dependency_injection

Comment: That was just an example actually, accessing the configuration factory in the `Configure` method gives the same result.

Comment: Ideally, what I wanted, was to set properties on the `ServicesConfigurator`, similar of how you can set properties through the Configuration Factory, but this is not available when configuring services configurators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Explanation

Your configurator is run as a part of the DI container initialization. During that phase, you cannot use the Sitecore Factory, because, starting from Sitecore 8.2, Factory uses the DI container under the hood. This restriction is apparently there to prevent configuration loops: container requests something from the Factory, the Factory falls back to the not-yet-initialized container, and so on.

Because of this, you cannot:

- Access Sitecore configuration when initializing the container;
- Instantiate objects using the Factory from your configurators;
- Inject properties or constructor parameters into the configurator itself.

### Suggestions

If you need to get parts of DI configuration from a file, you can:

- Read settings from your own configuration file (without using Sitecore Factory);
- Use `appSettings` / `applicationSettings` in the Web.config;
- [Substitute the underlying DI container](http://structuredcode.com/replacing-default-di-container-sitecore-8-2/) with something that supports custom configuration file format, such as [Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html);
- Use configuration-level injection of an implementation of a certain interface. That specific implementation will provide the settings — this way, settings are still set in the code, but are easily swappable from XML configuration.

Comment: This sums up my findings, so I guess what I am trying to accomplish is not possible. For now I will go with "configuration through code" and hardcode the needed values. Maybe I will explore alternative approaches later on.